# How to get new emails on the first try with imap_open in php

Tags: php, imap, imap-open

I have a PHP script which opens an email inbox, searches for the last email and then performs some other operations if this email has the UNSEEN header.

The script is run by a cron job, and it works fine. The problem is that sometimes it takes several attempts before actually finding the new email, even if the email has already arrived.

If someone sees i'm missing something, or knows how to ensure i get all emails on the first try, please let me know. This is the relevant email opening and searching code code:

```
//open mailbox
$inbox = imap_open('{<domain>/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', '<email-address>', '<password>');


$newEmails = false;
// grab a list of all the mail headers

$msgnos = imap_search($inbox, 'ALL');

$headers = imap_headers($inbox);


$last = imap_num_msg($inbox);

//check if the last email is marked as unread (U means unread)
    $headerinfo = imap_headerinfo($inbox, $last);
    if($headerinfo->Unseen == 'U') {
        $newEmails = true;
        file_put_contents("program_logs.txt","[".date('d-m-Y H:i') . "] program executed. New mails found. \r\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
    echo $headerinfo->Unseen . "<br>";

//read email if the last email is unread
if($newEmails == true){

    $header = imap_header($inbox, $last);
    $body = imap_fetchbody($inbox, $last,1);
    $structure = imap_fetchstructure($inbox, $last);
    $boxname = $header->from[0]->mailbox;
    $hostname = $header->from[0]->host;
    $title = $header->subject;
    $from = $boxname."@".$hostname;
    
    echo "<h2>Body structure Encoding:</h2>";
    var_dump($structure->encoding);
    echo "<hr>";

    if($structure->encoding == 3){
        $body = base64_decode($body);
    }
    if($structure->encoding == 4){
        $body=quoted_printable_decode($body);
    }
    
    echo "<h2>Is body html?</h2>";
    if($body != strip_tags($body)){
      echo "body is html.<br>";
      $body = preg_replace( "/\n\s+/", "\n", rtrim(html_entity_decode(strip_tags($body))) );
      echo "converted to plain text.";
     }else{
      echo "body is not html";
     }
     echo "<hr>";
    
    echo "<h2>From:</h2>".$from;
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "<h2>Body:</h2>".$body;
    echo "<hr>";
    echo "<h2>title:</h2>".$title;
    echo "<hr>";
    
    file_put_contents("program_logs.txt","Email is from ".$from. " \r\n",FILE_APPEND);

}else{
        echo 'No new notifications';
        echo "<hr>";
        echo "<h2>imap erros:</h2>";
        var_dump(imap_errors());
        imap_close($inbox);
        echo '<hr>';
        file_put_contents("program_logs.txt","[".date('d-m-Y H:i') . "] program executed, no new mails found. \r\n",FILE_APPEND);
    }
```